# Scanf asks for input twice

Tags: c

I'm making a program in which i need to ignore not alphabetical characters when reading input.

```
for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
        scanf(" %[A-Za-z]%*[^A-Za-z]s", A[i]);
    }
```

The problem is, it asks for input twice exclusively in the first pass of the loop (i = 0), in a way that the last input (i = size-1) is ignored, but still asked for. The repeated input takes the second place in the array.

Comment: Do you need to use `scanf()` like this?   I would just use `fgets()` (with stdin, never `gets()`), then just take what you want, and ignore the rest from the input string.

Comment: Unfortunately yes :/ professor does not like students using stuff he did not teach.

Comment: `%*[^A-Za-z]s` ?? from what depths did that emerge?

Comment: Despair in its rawest form.

Comment: I think it's pretty important you state what you think that does, because that misunderstanding is likely the root of your problem. The format string you've specified asks (1) skip leading whitespace. (2) consume and store everything until something not in the set `[A-Za-z]` is encountered, (3) consume and ignore everything in `[^A-Za-z]` (4) consume and ignore `'s'`. Is that what you intended? I suspect you should start by kicking out the `'s'` in that string.

Comment: Tried that, all it does is not ask for any input after a first one is given. And yes, (1) through is (3) exactly my intention.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre], including an exact copy of input that reproduces the problem, an exact copy of the observed output, and a sample of the desired output.

Comment: @O-Carneiro then tell your professor he should stop using his shoe to hammer a nail; that is the wrong tool for the job. Here `scanf` is the wrong tool.

Comment: What is the type of `A`?  I'm guessing it is some variation on `char A[20][32];`, but you should show us in the code.  You should put constraints on how many characters can be read into `A[i]` (e.g. `%31[A-Za-z]` for the `A` I suggested).  The `%*[^A-Za-z]` is quite literal-minded; it will eat as many newlines (blanks, digits, commas, colons, you name it) as you feed it, not stopping until it encounters another letter.  You should check the return value from `scanf()` to ensure you got `1`.  You may want want to include `\n` in that negated scan set (`%*[^A-Za-z\n]`).

Comment: O-Carneiro. `%[A-Za-z]` without a _width_ is unacceptable programming.  Include a width.